# How do I convert a string to Pandoc Inline data type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a pandoc script for some customized needs. I need to concate a character with a pandoc inline data type. The demo code below doesn't work, since caption is of type Inline while "a" is of type Char. How do I do this?

Para $ "a" ++ caption

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: It would help to know more, but note that the expression `"a" ++ caption` entails that it, "a" and 'caption', are all of the type `String`. `Para` doesn't take a raw String as argument, but a *list* of Inlines. First, then, we need to make "a" agree with this; the obvious way would be to write `Str "a"` since `Str` takes a string and makes an Inline. Then, if caption really is an individual inline, you could write `Para [Str "a", caption]` If, as seems likely, caption is already a list of Inlines, then `Para (Str "a" : caption)` should work. Other possibilities would be a bit more involved.